# How to refer to an element within an if statement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere but I just can't find what I'm looking for since I don't really know how to explain it.

I'll start with an example of my code

```
<script>
function choose(element){
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    var nextquestion = parseInt(parent.dataset.number)+1;
    parent.style.display = "none";

    if parseInt(getElementsByClassName("QuestionGroup").dataset.number) == nextquestion {
        WHATGOESHERE?.style.display = "inline";
    }
}
</script>
<div class="QuestionGroup" data-number="1" style="display:inline;">
<button onclick="choose(this);">An Answer</button></div>
<div class="QuestionGroup" data-number="2">Second Question</div>
```

So essentially, if the user clicks the button, choose() will check which question the button is part of. Then it will hide that group and unhide the second question group. It all works up to the part where I want to unhide the next question.

I use an if statement to check all elements with the class "QuestionGroup" for the data-number attribute and if that attribute is equal to the nextquestion variable, then I want to change the style of that element. The problem is, I don't have a clue how to actually reference that element to change the style.

Comment: [`if` statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5) needs parentheses around the condition.

Comment: if parseInt(getElementsByClassName("QuestionGroup").dataset.number) == nextquestion  should not work, because getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements. You need [single element].dataset.number

Comment: Oh geeze, you're kidding.

Comment: An `if` doesn't change change the scope. You still have access to the `element` and `parent` variables.

Comment: @MichaelWagner Specifically, `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` which is an array-like object. Probably, OP wants `document.getElementsByClassName("QuestionGroup")[0]` instead of `getElementsByClassName("QuestionGroup")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, thanks guys you've enlightened me immensely. I understand that javascript works a little differently to other languages I've used in the past.

Basically, you said that getElementsByClass returned an array of elements which is obviously not going to work there, so a little googling turned up this!

```
document.querySelector('[data-number="' + String(nextquestion) + '"]').style.display = "inline";
```

Instead of my terrible if statement!

Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent = element.parentNode;
var nextquestion = parseInt(parent.dataset.number)+1;
parent.style.display = "none";

if (parent.getElementsByClassName("QuestionGroup")[nextquestion]) {
    parent.getElementsByClassName("QuestionGroup")[nextquestion].style.display = "inline";
}
```

It's very hard to make up which parts of your code refer to what. This should work, but I don't know if it's going to give the desired result. Let me know or elaborate your question and code further.

As said `getElementsByClassName` returns a node list. You can check if the `index+1` exists. If so show it.